# Debugging SAXHandler unclosed token

Tags: xml, sax

I use SAXHandler to read XML and I get an error of the type
 `At line 3, column 244516: unclosed token`
Fine, I certainly have a problem in the input file, but I am uncertain on how to debug this problem. I dont really understand the concept of line and column here. Does this mean that the error is at byte number 244516 in the file and is related to the 3rd token?

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually quite clear. It means that there is an unclosed token in column 244516 of the third line of your XML data. Your XML data seems to have very long lines.